# Hide search value from LDAP query result

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have an ldap entry `cn=My Name,ou=users,dc=domain,dc=com` with these attributes among others:

```
mail: test@domain.com
mail: test2@domain.com
```

Then I perform and SEARCH with `LDAP_SCOPE_SUBTREE` on `ou=users,dc=domain,dc=com` with this query filter: `(mail=test@domain.com)` The requested attribute would be `mail`

The answer would be:

```
test@domain.com
test2@domain.com
```

But I only want `test2@domain.com` as result.

Is there a possility to do this with either the query filter *or* the OpenLDAP ACL?

I already tried the query filter: `(&(mail=test@domain.com)(!(mail=test2@domain.com)))`, but this returns an empty value

And my thought on doing this with ACL was to use something like `attrs=mail val=*searchquery*` as "What to control access to"-part, but the [documentation](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html#What%20to%20control%20access%20to) on this is not very detailed.

Any idea or better any solution for this problem? (and no, changing this to two different attributes is not really an option)

Comment: No. Adjusting the query filter will only affect what nodes are returned, not what attribute values are returned with them. There isn't a search syntax for what you want. What is the basis on which the second value is the one you want?

Comment: The background is a postfix-mailserver which is used with LDAP as user/forwarding database. The structure is a that each user has in the mail-attribute his*her user-account/mail-address. If the user just has a forwarding address, the address is stored in mailForwardingAttribute and the destination-address is in mail-attribute. Now I have a user which has a mail-account an uses the forwarding-feature. This ends that he gets every mail twice... But then I should rethink the LDAP structure...

Comment: What you've just described isn't what it says in your question, and it doesn't answer my question either. Why does the user have a two-valued `mail` attribute? and on what possible basis can you choose between them?